# Javascript function not getting Windows username

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

```
function getWindowsUserName()
{
    var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    var urlToSite = "http://localhost/index.php?nph-psf=0&HOSTID=AD&ALIAS=" + WinNetwork.UserName;      
    window.frames["psyncLink"].src = "http://localhost/index.php?nph-psf=0&HOSTID=AD&ALIAS=" + WinNetwork.UserName;
    return;
}
```

I am trying to make the frame load the urlToSite

```
<body onload="getWindowsUserName()">
    <frameset cols="300px, *"> 
        <frame src="topo1.htm" name="topo" id="topo" application="yes" /> 
        <frame src="topo1.htm" name="psyncLink" id="psyncLink" application="yes" /> 
    </frameset> 
</body>
```

Actually now I am just getting a blank page. If i visit the same site in IE and manually type the username (case is not sensitive) then the page loads in IE. Therefore I think it's something in the code thats the issue

---

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>AIDS (Automated ID System)</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION 
    id="frames" 
    border="thin" 
    caption="yes" 
    icon="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" 
    showintaskbar="yes" 
    singleinstance="yes" 
    sysmenu="yes" 
    navigable="yes" 
    contextmenu="no" 
    innerborder="no" 
    scroll="auto" 
    scrollflat="yes" 
    selection="yes" 
    windowstate="normal" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function getWindowsUserName()
    {
        var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
        var urlToSite = createCustomURL(WinNetwork.UserName);
        document.getElementById("psyncLink").src = urlToSite;
    }

    function createCustomURL(userName)
    {
        var customURL = "http://localhost/index.php?nph-psf=0&HOSTID=AD&ALIAS=" + userName;
        return customURL;
    }

</script>

    </head> 
    <body onload="getWindowsUserName()">
        <frameset cols="300px, *"> 
            <frame src="topo1.htm" name="topo" id="topo" application="yes" /> 
            <frame src="topo1.htm" name="psyncLink" id="psyncLink" application="yes" /> 
        </frameset> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any further information? ie What error are you getting?

Comment: No error. Nothing happens. Just a blank white screen

Comment: The basic problem seems to be `body` and `frameset` in the same page, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Teemu that worked. Put it as a solution(answer) so you can gain rep!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though nested `frameset` in `body` is not allowed, in "old-days" `body` element was included after `frameset` for those browsers which didn't support frames. This still works in IE9 Standards -mode, but then you can't see frames.

To execute `getWindowsUserName()` after the page has been loaded, you can do something like this:

```
   window.onload=getWindowsUserName;
</script>
</head>
<frameset cols="300,*">
   <frame src="" name="topo" ...>
   <frame src="topo1.htm" name="psyncLink" ...>
</frameset>
```

or maybe move `getWindowsUserName()` to topo1.htm.

More info of [`frameset` in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems:

- JavaScript uses `+` for concatenation, not `&`
- Property names are case sensitive. Try `WinNetwork.UserName`
- You're trying to set the `src` attribute of the frame window, that doesn't exist. You need to set the src of the frame DOM object. That is, `window.frames` returns a Window object and `document.getElementById('')` returns a reference to the HTMLFrameElement
- (From Teemu) You cannot have a frameset and a body tag on the same page.

Code

```
var urlToSite = "http://localhost/index.php?nph-psf=0&HOSTID=AD&ALIAS=" +
                 encodeURIComponent(WinNetwork.UserName);


document.getElementById("psyncLink").src = urlToSite;
```

**Reference** http://www.pctools.com/guides/scripting/detail/108/?act=reference

Comment: Thanks for the code fixes but the frame will not load the page. It's a blank page!

Comment: Did you attempt to debug what the value in `urlToSite` is?

Comment: Yea i did. urlTOSite is correct. I can copy and paste it into IE and it will load

Comment: You have an id not a name so instead of frames[]; `document.getElementById("psyncLink").src = urlToSite;`

Comment: What are you doing editing JS if you don't know examine the value of a variable? Sorry for the snarkiness... The simplest way is `alert(urlToSite)`;

Comment: Also if the username is `domain\user` don't forget to replace the \ with \\

Comment: @AlexK. That is not true, if the domain\user has a `\ ` it'll already be in a string, no need to re-escape it with a backslash. However, since it's being passed to a URL, you should use `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: the username doesn't require the domain. The value from UserName is correct. I'll try the document.getElement

Comment: @AlexK. The OP does have a name. However, that is part of the problem, `window.frames` returns a reference to the `Window` object. Whereas `document.getElementById('')` returns a reference to the HTMLFrameElement object.

Comment: I am posting my most updated code above. It's loading a blank page.